# Determining Slant Asymptote using $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ for $(1-x^3)^{1/3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the following function for which I am able to determine the slant asymptote of by find the limit of this function over $x$ as $x \to \infty$,
$$(1-x^3)^{1/3}$$
The result of this limit is $-1$, so I know that is the coefficient, k, of the asymptote $y=kx+b$. Now I am trying to find the $b$ term by evaluating
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) - kx = \lim_{x\to \infty} (1-x^3)^{1/3} + x$$
I multiply by the conjugate and simplify as follows,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1-x^3}{x[(x^{-3}-1)^{1/3}-1]}$$
Now I divide out the X's and substitute the limit, but no matter what I get inifinity as the result of this limit. Does this mean the asymptote is simply $-x$ or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: $$b=\lim_{x\to \infty} ((1-x^3)^{1/3} + x) \times \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{(1-x^3)^2} - x\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}+x^2}{\sqrt[3]{(1-x^3)^2} - x\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}+x^2}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(1-x^3)^2} - x\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}+x^2}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{1}{x^2\left(\sqrt[3]{(\frac{1}{x^3}-1)^2} - \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{x^3}-1}+1\right)}=0$$

Comment: @Danielle your solution is right until the multiplication by the conjugate. You did it as if there were a square root, not a third. Nosrati wrote the correct one.